# RoutingError uninitialized constant Subscribers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Somehow i get this routing error. I don't see the solution

My controller:

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  def signup
    blabla...
  end
  etc.....
end
```

My routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'signup' => 'subscribers/#signup'
  resources :events
  resources :subscribers

  root to: 'events#index'

end
```

so if i go to http://0.0.0.0:3000/signup
I get the error: RoutingError uninitialized constant Subscribers

Comment: rewrite this `'subscribers/#signup'` to `'subscribers#signup'`

Comment: Arghhh the slash... Thanks!

Comment: putting as an answer for future reference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/` stands for namespace or folder and `#` is used for action in the routes. you just need to remove `/` as `signup` is an action under `SubscribersController`:

```
get 'signup' => 'subscribers#signup'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your have `resources :subscribers` so best way to declare route for non `CRUD` operation like

```
resources :subscribers do
  member { post :foo } # if is member (operation on single obj) with http post
  collection { get :bar } # for collection with http get
end
```

So the best solution for your problem is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :events

  resources :subscribers do
      collection { get :signup }
    end

  root to: 'events#index'
end
```

For more information see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html